# Is there an alternative way to convert coordinates for rects?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I fell into a trap, and it's too late to refactor everything. For reasons that are too long to explain here (but they are valid and the codebase works fine), I had to abstract away `UIImageViews` as a return type in one of the methods, and instead I only return a procotol.
This protocol, called `Viewable`, has only 5 properties.

```
    protocol Viewable {

        var image: UIImage { get }
        var bounds: CGRect { get }
        var center: CGPoint { get }
        var contentMode: UIViewContentMode { get }
        var hidden: Bool { get set }
    }
```

A viewable is a view that is viewable in `UIView` hierarchy, nothing special there.. The problem is following:

I need to extend this protocol so that I can have a convenience method with better semantics that would calculate the coordinates of viewable in a different parent coordinate system.

For normal `UIView` the code would look like this, and it works just fine.

```
 extension UIView {

     func frame(inCoordinatesOfView parentView: UIView) -> CGRect {

            let frameInWindow = UIApplication.applicationWindow.convertRect(self.bounds, fromView: self)
            return parentView.convertRect(frameInWindow, fromView: UIApplication.applicationWindow)
    }
}
```

But when I do this

```
extension Viewable {

     func frame(inCoordinatesOfView parentView: UIView) -> CGRect {

            let frameInWindow = UIApplication.applicationWindow.convertRect(self.bounds, fromView: self)
            return parentView.convertRect(frameInWindow, fromView: UIApplication.applicationWindow)
    }
}
```

Of course it doesn't work because the part `fromView:self` won't compile. The type there is expected to be `UIView` not `Viewable`.

So to return to my header, is there a way to calculate coordinates without the need to reference UIViews, instead it would be a pure math formula only dealing with `CGRect`s & `CGPoint`s?

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend the protocol in this way:

```
extension Viewable where Self: UIView {

        func frame(inCoordinatesOfView parentView: UIView) -> CGRect {

            let frameInWindow = UIApplication.applicationWindow.convertRect(self.bounds, fromView: self)
            return parentView.convertRect(frameInWindow, fromView: UIApplication.applicationWindow)
        }
    }
```

I havent tested it myself but should work. Let me know what happens.

```
extension Viewable where Self: UIView {
```

**will only add the functionality if the conforming Type is a UIView**

. In that case, there is a `convertRect` and hence the extension will not error.

Comment: The devil is in the details as they say :). Viewable is not always a UIView (or a subclass of it)...it could also be a ASDisplayNode from AsyncDisplayKit.